# Linked image and Warp effect Problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, file-placing

Example file:
[image]

I am experiencing some problems in maintaining linkage in PSD images that i warp to special mold for conic mugs.

By this i mean that Warp effect only accepts embedded images to perform the warp in an image.

The problem is that i loose all the versatility of the link feature and if i need to change anything in the PSD image i than have to remake the warp.

Do You have a way to go around this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, not in Illustrator. Raster images require embedding for many operations involving transformations.

It may be best to warp a Smart Object within Photoshop, unless there's a reason you specifically need Illustrator here.

Edited to add:

If you highlight a layer in Photoshop, and choose `Edit > Transform > Warp` then look at the control bar across the top of the screen, the options are the same as the envelope warp in Illustrator. Just input the same values. If you do this to a Smart Object in Photoshop, you can just double-click the Smart Object to replace it's contents (swap the internal image), retaining the warp settings on the Smart Object.

Comment: As a matter of fact i don't know how to warp an image to a specified form in photoshop as i do in illustrator by the cmd+alt+c. It comes very handy and most of the times precise enough and i don't even have to turn to barco's Mosaic software for that.  Can you help on how to warp in this way in photoshop ? Because as i know it is progressive  and not at once. Thanks

Comment: @LuisMonteiro See the updated answer...